# ERROR: function lower(text[]) does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my table I have a column with type text[], I need to convert the whole column value from uppercase to lowercase. As the lower function is not working here is there any way to convert it into lowercase?

```
id   value
1     {HELLO,VALUE}
2     {HELLO}
3     {HELLO}
```

How can update all values of the value column to lowercase?
value column is of type text[].

```
id   value
1     {hello,value}
2     {hello}
3     {hello}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your expression to convert every array element to lower case:

```sql
select array_agg(lower(s)) from unnest("value") as s;
```

and for the table:

```sql
select id, (select array_agg(lower(s)) from unnest("value") as s) as "value" from _table;
```

Update the whole table:

```sql
update _table set "value" = (select array_agg(lower(s)) from unnest("value") as s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you collecting some small useful functions somewhere that could be used in your projects.

```
create function array_lower(text[]) returns text[] stable strict language sql
as $$ select array_agg(lower(x)) from unnest($1) as x $$;

create function array_upper(text[]) returns text[] stable strict language sql
as $$ select array_agg(upper(x)) from unnest($1) as x $$;

select  array_lower('{AAA,BbB}'), array_upper('{AAA,Bbb}');
┌─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ array_lower │ array_upper │
├─────────────┼─────────────┤
│ {aaa,bbb}   │ {AAA,BBB}   │
└─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Then

```
select id, array_lower(value) as val_lower from your_table;

update your_table set value = array_lower(value);
```

---

Update

As mentioned by @Stefanov.sm the functions with names `array_lower/array_upper` already exists and have different prototype/meaning (first and last indexes in the array)

While proposed functions is not "physically" conflicts with existing one you could to name them in more convenient way like `text_array_lower` or `array_text_lower` or even `lower_case_of_all_that_damned_values_in_this_damned_array_ugh`.

Comment: Just a remark - array_upper and array_lower are names of existing functions (though with different prototypes). Better use s/th like textarray_upper and textarray_lower to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm You are right. Actually that's because I using `create` instead of `create or replace`. Personally I preferring to name an objects like `<set>_<subset>_<nature/action>` so in this case: `array_text_lower`. But it is matter of taste of course.